# Meteor - how to give tracker autorun a callback

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a little piece of code that renders data from the database according to the path name.  My only problem is that when I try to retrieve that data, using `this.state.note._id` it returns an error that says it cannot find `_id` of undefined.  How would I access my object that is put into a state?  It only gives the error when I try to access the items inside the object such as `_id`

```
import React from "react";
import { Tracker } from "meteor/tracker";

import { Notes } from "../methods/methods";

export default class fullSize extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      note: [],
      document: (<div></div>)
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      Meteor.subscribe('notes');
      let note = Notes.find({_id: this.props.match.params.noteId}).fetch()
      this.setState({ note: note[0] });
    });
  }
  renderDocument(){
    console.log(this.state.note);
    return <p>Hi</p>
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.tracker.stop();
  }
  render(){
    return <div>{this.renderDocument()}</div>
  }
}
```

I know that the reason it is returning undefined is because (correct me if I am wrong) the page is rendering the function before the the tracker could refresh the data.  How would I get like some sort of callback when the tracker receives some data it will call the renderDocument function?

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your `note` state as an *array* but then you're setting it to a scalar later. You're also not checking to see if the subscription is *ready* which means that you end up trying to get the state when it is still empty. The tracker will run *anytime a reactive data source inside it changes*. This means you don't need a callback, you just add any code you want to run inside the tracker itself.

You also don't need a state variable for the document contents itself, your render function can just return a `<div />` until the subscription becomes ready.

Note also that `.findOne()` is equivalent to `.find().fetch()[0]` - it returns a single document.

When you're searching on `_id` you can shorthand your query to `.findOne(id)` instead of `.findOne({_id: id})`

```
import React from "react";
import { Tracker } from "meteor/tracker";

import { Notes } from "../methods/methods";

export default class fullSize extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      note: null
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const sub = Meteor.subscribe('notes');
    this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      if (sub.ready) this.setState({ note: Notes.findOne(this.props.match.params.noteId) });
    });
  }
  renderDocument(){
    return this.state.note ? <p>Hi</p> : <div />;
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.tracker.stop();
  }
  render(){
    return <div>{this.renderDocument()}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: It still returns the same error.. it says, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined` and gives a typeerror that says, `Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent`

Comment: Can you show the code where you're accessing `this.state.note._id` or `...title`? Also are you sure that (a) `this.props.match.params.noteId` has a value and (b) that `Notes.findOne(this.props.match.params.noteId)` is returning an actual document?

Comment: `  renderDocument(){
    console.log(this.state.note._id)
  }`  I am trying to make a page to render the whole note object with the title, imageURL, and note creator.  Right now I am just having troubles with consoling the items inside the state.  And to answer your questions. (a)yes, this.props.match.params.noteId does in fact return the note id just as I would like (b)yes it returns an object with all the data stored in it

Comment: So `console.log(this.state.note)` returns null or undefined and never gets updated? Just out of curiosity, why are you not following the more typical `createContainer` pattern to make your component reactive?

Comment: Okay, I found out that when I was trying to retrieve the data from the state in the log I was refreshing the page each time I made a change.  However, when I went back to the home page on clicked on the note(renders the fullSize component) my app works fine and as expected, would you know any reason for that?

Comment: Not sure, that seems quite odd.